# How do I have to multiply the following 4darrays to obtain a 2d array in Pytorch?

Tags: matrix, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I am using Pytorch. I have a 4d array with shape (C, H, W, K) and I want to multiply it to another 4d-array with shape (N, C, H, W).
I want a final 2-d matrix (N, K).
How should I implement this in Pytorch?
And, more generally, how does higher order matrix multiplication works? Are there any rules to keep in mind in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) to reshape the 4D tensors into simple 2D matrices and then multiply them

```py
x1 = x1.view(-1, x1.shape[-1])  # from C-H-W-k -> CHW-K
x2 = x2.view(x2.shape[0], -1)   # from N-C-H-W -> N-CHW
out = x2 @ x1  # matrix multiplication
```

Note that the complexity of `view`, in generalm is minimal as it usually does not incur copying and moving of tensor values in memory - only changes to the header of the tensor representation.

For more advanced and more flexible tensor multiplication, you might want to look at [`einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum).